# How to start Viber minimized on system startup?

Tags: startup, minimize, viber

I use ViberIndicator to start Viber with correctly display tray icon on Ubuntu 15.10. Then I added viberIndiator to startups applications Viber start with displaying last dialog window.

How to start Viber minimized on system startup ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure your linux startup commands (Properties - Startup - Viber) for Viber:

```
/opt/viber/Viber StartMinimized
```

Comment: Added details .

Comment: At least it is minimized as window.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should combine **@zon** and **@yavor-dobrev** solutions with a bit of tricks.

I use this startup script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0
/opt/viber/Viber StartMinimized &

while ! wmctrl -xc Viber.ViberPC; do
    sleep .5
done
```

**Details:**

- `export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0` to avoiding huge display on my XFCE4
- `Viber StartMinimized` to starting Viber hidden as possible
- `wmctrl -xc Viber.ViberPC` to closing the Viber window only avoid closing others
- `while ! wmctrl ...` to close the windows as fast it can

Answer (score 1):

Install wmctrl and use the following script to start viber:

```
#!/bin/bash
/opt/viber/Viber &
sleep 3
wmctrl -c "Viber"
```

Adjust the sleep time if necessary.